# Exception thrown while debugging kafka consumer

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-kafka-dotnet

Following exception is thrown while debugging this specific code line. The execption is thrown after the specified time set (5 minutes) after exiting the kafka consume method.

```
private void OnCheckPartitionAssignmentTimerElapsed(object? state)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!_isConsumerClosed)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(kconsumer?.MemberId))
                {
                    logger.Warning($"Consumer has left group, MemeberId: {kconsumer?.MemberId}. Cancelling the task...");
                    taskToken.Cancel();
                }
            }
        } 
        catch (ObjectDisposedException e)
        {
            logger.Error($"Topics - {string.Join(",",kconsumer?.Subscription)} - {e}");
        }
    }
```

[image]

The same line of code throws exception in deployed environment.

```
Unhandled exception. System.ObjectDisposedException: handle is destroyed
   at Confluent.Kafka.Impl.SafeKafkaHandle.ThrowIfHandleClosed()
   at Confluent.Kafka.Impl.SafeKafkaHandle.GetSubscription()
   at Confluent.Kafka.Consumer`2.get_Subscription()
   at Kore.Analytics.Shared.Kafka.Consumer.SharedKafkaConsumer.SharedKafkaConsumer`2.OnCheckPartitionAssignmentTimerElapsed(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire(Boolean isThreadPool)
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading.PortableThreadPool.WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart()
   at System.Threading.Thread.StartCallback()
```

Couldnt understand the reason behind this exception